# Unicorn can't start in production with railtie.rb:39: uninitialized constant Sass::Rails::SassTemplate (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, unicorn, initialization

After migrating from Rails 3.0.10 to 3.1.3 i get this error on my production server (in development app works ok):
I have

```
railtie.rb:39: uninitialized constant Sass::Rails::SassTemplate (NameError)
```

in unicorn.stderr.log

There is my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'acts_as_indexed'
gem 'ancestry'
gem 'awesome_nested_set'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'dragonfly'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'haml'
gem 'has_unique_slug'
gem 'hipchat'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'json'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'meta-tags', :require => 'meta_tags'
gem 'meta_search', '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem 'rack-rewrite'
gem 'russian'
gem 'sass-rails', '  ~> 3.1.0'
gem 'sorcery', :git => 'https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery.git'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'time_diff'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'yaml_db'
```

Any help is appreciated! My site is down now!

Comment: I don't what it was :((. After migrating to 1.9.3@3.2.1 all is ok.